# Unable to import name spaces using quick fix (Visual Studio Code)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-2.0

Hi everyone,
            I have a problem with my visual studio code. Initially, when I installed the extensions and used the Visual Studio Code, there would be a red line under the name if I had not referenced the namespace and there would be a yellow light bulb(quick fix) to recommend me to import the namespace using etc etc. However, it doesn't do that anymore. And there used to be the number of references on top of the field name eg, 1 references on top of the public int Id{get;set;} etc. I have tried installing my extensions again but it does not seem to solve the problem. Anyone has a clue on how I resolve that? Thank you.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace vega.Models
{
    public class Make
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } 

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Model> Models { get; set; }

        public Make()
        {
            Models = new Collection<Model>();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like CodeLens is disabled in Visual Studio Code.

You can enable it in Visual Studio via the Options menu item under Tools.
In the Options screen goto Text Editor - All Languages - Code Lens and enable it there.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the post as the good answer.